# Django model -- Not able to show all the objects

Tags: django, model

Am new to Django. My question is

```
from A.models import CustomerRequest

p = CustomerRequest.objects.all()

print p

Result: [<CustomerRequest: CustomerRequest object>]
```

Why the result showing only this eventhough I have lots of data inside my database model. please help

Comment: `[]` generally means there is in fact no data in the QuerySet... can you try the following in your django console and let us know what happens? 1) `new_obj = CustomerRequest.objects.create(ENTER REQUIRED PARAMETERS HERE)` 2) `print new_obj`

Comment: Result: [<CustomerRequest: CustomerRequest object>]. I dont know why in my question its not showing even i typed the same result.

Comment: Access your database and just query your CustomerRequest table with select * from ... and check what really is stored there